# How to generate an audit event (on Kubernetes) when a new node joins a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following rule in my audit policy:

```
- level: RequestResponse
    verbs: ["create","update","patch"]
    resources:
      - group: "" # core
        resources: ["nodes"]
```

My objective is to generate a new audit event in the kubernetes audit log when a new node joins the cluster.
However, when I join a new node and search for events like so:

`more /var/log/audit.log | jq 'select(.objectRef.resource == "nodes" and .kind != "Event")'`

I do not get the expected event.
What am I missing?